# How to use IN inside of CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT T_MW.*
INTO #temp
FROM T_MWP T_MW
WHERE T_MW.CompanyID = 2
AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN @Currency IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                    T_MW.Currency IN (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM #Currency
                        )
                    )
        END
    )
AND (
    CASE 
        WHEN @Asset IS NOT NULL
            THEN (
                    T_MW.Asset IN (
                        SELECT *
                        FROM #Asset
                        )
                    )
        END
    )
```

Here #Asset is a table containing assets and #Currency is a temporay table containing Currency. #Asset and #Currency are created using following query

```
SELECT *
INTO #Asset
FROM dbo.Split(@Asset, ',');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use OR Instead of Case

```
SELECT 
T_MW.*
INTO #temp
FROM T_MWP T_MW
WHERE T_MW.CompanyID = 2
AND 
(
    (
       @Currency IS NOT NULL
       AND 
       T_MW.Currency IN 
       (
          SELECT * FROM #Currency
       )
    )
    OR
    @Currency IS NULL
)
AND 
(
    (
       @Asset IS NOT NULL
       AND
       T_MW.Asset IN 
       (
            SELECT * FROM #Asset
        )
    )
    OR
    @Asset IS NULL
)
```

Comment: @Currency IS NOT NULL OR T_MW.Currency will the right answer

Comment: Thanks for letting me known how to use in inside of where clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
T_MW.*
INTO #temp
FROM T_MWP T_MW
WHERE T_MW.CompanyID = 2
AND 
(
(
   @Currency IS NOT NULL
   OR 
   T_MW.Currency IN 
   (
      SELECT * FROM #Currency
   )
)
)
AND 
(
(
   @Asset IS NOT NULL
   OR
   T_MW.Asset IN 
   (
        SELECT * FROM #Asset
    )
)
)
```